# How to Retrieve History from ALL browsers on Android Phone

Tags: browser-history

I am using Samsung Galaxy Note 1. I have access to my google account which I used to sign into my android phone. However, I am only able to see history of websites visited using google chrome, but not other browsers. I am basically using two browsers only that are google chrome and CM Browser. I am able to see history of websites visited on chrome browser, but not CM Browser. One more interesting and important thing! CM browser only stores the history of websites that user visted 2 days ago or the same day the browser was used to visit website. Is there any way I could see history of visited websites on all browsers of my phone?

Comment: You could install a proxy/VPN to see all traffic for future connections but nothing you can do now.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no one place that all browsers store history. Each browser stores history in its own way. Chrome stores it in the cloud, associated with your Google account. Firefox can store it in the cloud with a Firefox account, but doesn't share it with Google. I don't know about CM Browser but maybe they don't store it in the cloud at all, only on your phone.

Most people who use other browsers than Chrome would be very annoyed if their browser told Google about every website they visited.